# Hide child pages from menu tree

Tags: navigation, breadcrumbs

Hopefully some wise Drupal guru will be able to help me with this one.

I'm using menu and menu block to output a side menu in Drupal 7.  Using Panelizer, on a basic page I can customize display and add a view pane (Case study: Teaser), which will display a list of case study teasers:

[image]

I can add a case study content type, which provides a menu link.  The problem is over time there will likely be hundreds of case studies, and it will look unwieldly to have hundrens of children/sub-pages in the menu.

I could list the links and disable them from the menu (and also keep the breadcrumb path):
[image]

However, various admin and editors will be using this, so ideally I'd like some functionality whereby sub-pages do not appeaer in the menu when a Case Study content type is used, but the breadcrumb path is still shown:
[image]

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be eternally grateful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the case studies to appear in the secondary nav/sidebar menu, you could try using the [Path Breadcrumbs module](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBu-jM-ZvYAhUl2oMKHVMcCy0QFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Fpath_breadcrumbs&usg=AOvVaw2QfyTk52wBxQrsTtrgCFBb) to set custom rules for any of the following scenarios:

- all "Case Study" content resides in a fixed hierarchy
- "Case Study" content with a specific tag goes in a fixed hierarchy
- "Case Study" content breadcrumbs are defined by url alias/path that reflects parent pages.

The module is rather flexible in the rulesets you can define.

Comment: Thank you @anson-w-han I'll try this when I'm back at work after Christmas.

Comment: Hi @anson-w-han, I've tried adding an argument and selection rule, but can't figure out how to set custom rule for all "Case Study" content resides in a fixed hierarchy.  Should I be able to find 'content type' to choose the argument?

Comment: Can anyone shed any light on this?